# Magento Community v1.7 category grid image size

Tags: html, css, magento

Im having trouble resizing my images for the following page.

http://arc-iris.com/eyewear.html

Here is the code for relevant image file /app/design/frontend/default/arciris/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

```
<img id="open_clos_<?php echo $i ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(320,214); ?>" alt="" /></span></a>
```

Here is the css code

.products-grid .product-image { display:block; width:320px; height:214px; margin:0 0 0 0;  border:1px solid #727272; }

Any suggestions of what would be making the image smaller?  The images are stuck at 300x190px.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're editing the wrong template. Image from your link has completely different html, there isn't your id, there are width and height attributes, hence the wrong dimensions and image real dimensions are 610x407 so its not being resized.

```
<img width="300px" height="190px" alt="" src="http://arc-iris.com/media/catalog/category/solar-buckeye-plexitable.jpg">
```

css isn't helping because its referring to images parent `<a>` and it indeed has that style, also you can shorten `margin:0 0 0 0;` to `margin:0;`

Check with template path hints if the right template is loaded, if yes check that all folders and template name are correct. Let me know if this helped.